# Solving a Bernoulli diff eqn.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

in trying to solve the given problem:

$t^2\frac{dy}{dt}+y^2=ty$

$t^2dy+(y^2-ty)dt=0$

I have made the variable substitution  $u=y/t$, $dy=-\frac{du}{t^2}$

$t^2du+(u^2+t^2u)dt=0$

which is a Bernoulli type of equation. However, here no integrating factor is found by either  multiplying with $e^{\int(u^2+t^2u)du}$ or by using $e^{\int\frac{M_t-N_u}{N}}$ or $e^{\int\frac{N_u-M_t}{M}}$.

At wolfram alpha, this is solved to:

$y(t) = \frac{e^t t}{(c_1 t - t Ei(t) + e^t)}$ . But how does this come about?

Thanks

Comment: why does Wolfram alpha shows the solution as function of $x$ when the original ode is function of   $t$ ?

Comment: Corrected. Just aesthetical choice at WA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t^2\frac{dy}{dt}+y^2=ty$

$\frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{y}{t}=-\frac{y^2}{t^2}$

This is a bernoulli equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$

The transformation is $v=y^{1-n}$

$v=y^{1-2}=\frac{1}{y}$

$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dt}$

Substituting in original differential equation, we get

$\frac{dv}{dt}+ \frac{v}{t}=\frac{1}{t^2}$

Therefore the general solution is

$v=e^{-\int\frac{dt}{t}}\int e^{\int \frac{dt}{t}}\frac{dt}{t^2}+c$

Answer (score 0):

$$t^2\frac{dy}{dt}+y^2=ty$$
$$t^2\frac{dy}{dt}-ty=-y^2$$
$$y-ty'=\dfrac {y^2}t$$
$$\left ( \dfrac {t}{y}\right)'=\dfrac 1t$$
Integrate.
$$\dfrac {t}{y}=\ln t+C$$
$${y}(t)=\dfrac  t {\ln t+C}$$